# Set a variable of Date type as value in a HTML date input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I get a date from my server with the Date type. I save it in my state, and try to use it as value in an date input as seen below:

```
<input type="date"
       id="start"
       name="trip-start"
       value={this.state.changeEndDate}
       min="2018-01-01" />
```

I get an error, as I can't assign the Date to int. Is it anywhere I could solve this? Or use another form/input field that actually supports Date format.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just try converting it to a string using

```
this.state.changeEndDate.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worth trying

```
{{this.state.changeEndDate | date}}
```

Comment: The question is about react not angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Be carefull on the date object contructor parameter, [See doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
<input
  type="date"
  id="start"
  name="trip-start"
  value={new Date(this.state.changeEndDate)}
  min="2018-01-01" />
```